# IPN not being received on my host (HTTP Response code is NULL)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am not able to receive any IPN Notifications on my server, checked IPN History page, i see no HTTP Response code there. A month ago, it was working all fine and then stopped all a sudden. I inquired with hosting guys and they said they have no firewall blocking any of the paypal ip addresses (https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/92/kw/IPN/related/1).

I also checked cPanel's Raw Access Log and i cannot find any request made to script "test-ipn.php". If i run this script manually via browser, i see it on Raw Access Log, but when i try with Simulator, it doesn't show up, which seems like Paypal is not posting at all.

However i tried a different url on different host to test with IPN Simulator and it worked there, but not working on the current host.

Any ideas?

Plz advice, thx!

Here's the Screenshot of IPN History page: http://www.247autohits.com/paypal.jpg

**UPDATE:**

Problem is still there, its keep coming back after restarting apache.
I did some research and found a clue that there is something wrong with HTTP-POST either at the `Firewall` end or at the `mod_sec`. Because, i used this code to test my host by sending a HTTP POST via PHP cURL and it responded with HTTP CODE 0.

Then i restarted Apache (fixes ipn temporarily) and re-run this code and it returned correct response code 200.

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init("http://www.xxxxxx.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('testing paypal sandbox'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Paypal Sandbox Test Localhost'));
$res = curl_exec($ch);

if(!curl_errno($ch)){
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo '<div>Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'].'</div>';
}

echo "<div><strong>".strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE))."</strong></div>";
?>
```

I believe HTTP-POST is being restricted by Firewall or mod_sec, not at the initial level but after some time or maybe when something is invoked/alarmed, to possibly prevent from some attack or anything like that.

Comment: any url rewriting going on in the likes of .htaccess ?

Comment: @Dagon nope, nothing there.

Comment: if everything is 100% in the question it looks like its the host, i would talk to them again.

Comment: There has to be something for status code in your IPN history...at least a 200 if it made it through.

Comment: @DavidNguyen IPN History shows blank. Here's the ss: http://www.247autohits.com/paypal.jpg

Comment: Something is definitely blocking if you can access the URL directly. You can see that it is still retrying.